# Error trying to import react-select to a project created with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
yarn create react-app
yarn add react-select
```

I created a react app using create-react-app, and it worked fine. 
Then I wanted to use react-select, so I installed it with yarn, added an import statement like `import Select from "react-select/src/Select";`

I got this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-select/src/Select.js
SyntaxError: ~~~~\node_modules\react-select\src\Select.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (3:32)

  1 | // @flow
  2 | 
> 3 | import React, { Component, type ElementRef, type Node } from 'react';
    |                                 ^
  4 | import memoizeOne from 'memoize-one';
  5 | import { MenuPlacer } from './components/Menu';
  6 | import isEqual from './internal/react-fast-compare';
```

I can see the `type` keyword is causing the issue and suspect it has to do with something named `flow` which seems a static type checker.
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 11):

Just import like

```
import Select from "react-select";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that: `import Select from "react-select";` as above may not be enough!

In my case, in VSCODE there are macros that when invoked, generates someting like:

```
import { valueFocusAriaMessage } from 'react-select/src/accessibility'
```

Comment out / delete the line to solve the syntax error problem.
I emphasize the issue since the line is added at the top, while you may not notice it!
Beware.